# Chamada de função de dll C# (VS2010) utilizando COM em Delphi 5 não passa os parâmetros corretamente

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

Bom dia,
Criei utilizando UnmanagedExports uma dll em c# (Visual Studio 2010) para ser consumida em um form delphi 5, conforme:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TesteDllCom
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("CE805AD4-511E-4E63-A37F-9FF6C97D664B")]
    public class TesteDll 
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static int TestarDll(int testeInt, string testeStr)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(testeStr);
            if (testeInt == 0)
            {
                 return 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 return 1;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Chamada da dll no Delphi:

```
unit frmTesteDll;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, WinInet, ComObj;

type
  TfrmTesteDll = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmTesteDll: TfrmTesteDll;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TfrmTesteDll.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TTesteDll = function (testeInt: Integer; testeStr: String): Integer;
var
  dllHandle: THandle;
  funcTestarDll: TTesteDll;
  retorno: Integer;
begin
   dllHandle :=  LoadLibrary('TesteDllCom.dll');
   @funcTestarDll := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'TestarDll');
   retorno := funcTestarDll(0, 'teste');
   if retorno <> 0 then
     ShowMessage('Erro');
end;

end.
```

No projeto c# marquei as opções "Make Assembly COM-Visible" e  "Register for COM interop".
A chamada da DLL é realizada corretamente, a função é ativada e tudo mais, porem ambas as minhas variáveis estão indo com valor incorreto, a mensagem gerada pelo trecho "MessageBox.Show(testeStr);" vem caracteres incorretos, e o retorno da função é 1. Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, alguém consegue me ajudar?

@EDIT - Resolvi gente, tava faltando adicionar a diretiva stdcall na declaração da referência da função da dll no delphi, conforme:

```
TTesteDll = function (testeInt: Integer; testeStr: String): Integer; stdcall;
```

Comment: Posta uma resposta para a pergunta então, para ficar documentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, na linha (do código Delphi):

```
TTesteDll = function (testeInt: Integer; testeStr: String): Integer;
```

estava faltando a diretiva `stdcall`.
Adicionei e funcionou perfeitamente.